# I need to rewrite this from a sub into a function

Tags: vb.net

This is the program I need to re-write and I dont understand.

```
Sub Main()

    Dim array(24) As Double, i As Long
    array(0) = 1

    For i = 1 To 24
        array(i) = 2 * array(i - 1)
    Next i

    Call DisplayArray(array)

End Sub

Sub DisplayArray(ByVal array() As Double)

    Dim i As Long, n As Long
    n = array.GetLength(0)

    For i = 0 To n - 1
        Console.WriteLine(array(i))
    Next i

End Sub
```

I need it to
be a function
with two parameters, an array and constant k
should return an array where each elemtn of the array is equal to k ^ i

Answer (score 0):

Well I can't really say I completely understand what you're doing.  And I suspect this might be a homework question I'm giving the answers too against my better judgement.  It's really not that complicated and likely something you could of done yourself with the appropriate research.

And calling a function for this does seem complete overkill as can be done quite simply when outputting your array in the DisplayArray method

```
Sub Main()

    Dim array(24) As Double, i As Long
    array(0) = 1

    For i = 1 To 24
        array(i) = 2 * array(i - 1)
    Next i

    'Calling the function here with the constant 3
    Dim results() As Double = CalculateResults(array, 3)

    Call DisplayArray(array)
    Call DisplayArray(results)

    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub

Sub DisplayArray(ByVal array() As Double)

    Dim i As Long, n As Long
    n = array.GetLength(0)

    For i = 0 To n - 1
        Console.WriteLine(array(i))
    Next i

End Sub

Function CalculateResults(ByVal array As Double(), ByVal k As Integer) As Double()

    Dim retVal(array.Length) As Double
    For index = 0 To array.Length
        retVal(index) = index ^ k
    Next
    Return retVal
End Function
```